# Linux Bash Scripting using grep sed and cut command to display ip address with port number

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, sed

Can any one please help me
I need a output of "192.168.1.1#53" by using these 'grep' 'sed' and 'cut' command mandatory in linux bash scipting
in given below text.

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Sep 19 12:20:54 BST 2020

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each element of the string is separated by a single space:

```
grep Query | cut -f8 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"("
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -Eo [0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\#[0-9]+ <filename>
```

The -E makes grep work like egrep

The -o returns only the matching parts